# Changing fonts at runtime and resizing controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an application where I am dynamically changing form font types and sizes at runtime. The forms and controls resize proportionally when the controls are added to the form itself but not when they are added to containers such as panel or group controls where they tend to overlap or not grow to accommodate larger text. Any pointers as to why this might be?

Comment: How about posting the relevant resizing code?

Comment: I am not doing anything special as far as resizing goes except that I have set the form's AutoScaleMode property to "Font" which works well except where controls are contained within other containers.

Comment: In the form's designer file, there is a line 
Me.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte)) 
If this appears BEFORE Me.Controls.Add(Me.PanelControl1) etc etc, my problem is resolved. However, if I simply change a property of any control on the form, it reverts automatically to being placed after and the issue recurs.

Comment: How about if you leave it where the designer puts it, and also put it in the form's `Load` event?

Comment: That won't work. It needs to be called before adding the controls and containers to the form and the form load event is decidedly later. I am wondering whether there is a form property that will change this behaviour to the behaviour that I want to see.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the font and size you use this:

```
Me.Font = New Font("Verdana", 12)

Me.Size = New Size(20, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that this was an issue specific to the DevExpress XtraForm. I resolved it by adding this to the form's constructor:

```
Font = (New Form()).Font
```

So my form's constructor looks like this:

```
Public Sub New()
    Font = (New Form()).Font

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```